# How do I add a unit test target to a notification service extension for an app?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

I have a notification service extension and I need to add a target for unit testing, but the option for adding the unit test target to the SE is greyed out. What is the best way to get a test target to hit my SE?

Comment: Same problem here, do you found a solution? I would have preferred not to add the extension files to the App test target.