# Connecting a Unit Test file with another file that has a Target Membership to Notification Service Extension

Tags: ios, swift

I have a unit test and file thats called "NotificationService.swift" that has Target Membership to NotificationServiceExtension. The code works. its just every time I try run my unit test with this file I have trouble linking the unit test file with the "NotificationService.swift". I did some searching on Stack and found this: [How do I add a unit test target to a notification service extension for an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49059536/how-do-i-add-a-unit-test-target-to-a-notification-service-extension-for-an-appurl()). But it seems no one has answered it. Any help would be great.